# How do the regular expressions identify a line with a string made of two equal parts in the following code?

Tags: python, regex

The following code is out of many input lines printing the ones that contain a word which is made of two equal parts.

## For example:

input: DAAD is a foundation.
output: DAAD is a foundation.

input: DA AD is a foundation.
output: N/A

Please explain the 'if' statement below:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(r"\b(\w+)\1\b", line) is not None:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b(\w+)\1\b/
```

\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
1st Capturing Group (\w+)

\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

https://regex101.com/r/1YuvP8/2

Basically in order for a line to print it needs to have a group of characters of any size with the characters [a-zA-Z0-9_] print out twice together

DADA would which result in match. DA_DA_ would result in a match as well.
DA DA would not, because the regex does not match white space.